# Step-by-step-by-step procedure for enabling mod_mono on OSX

Tags: macos, mod-mono

I'm running OSX Leopard 10.5.8.
Apache is working.
Mono framework 2.10 has been installed and is working.
XCode has been installed and is working.
The mod_mono source code 2.10 has been downloaded and detarred.

I need a step-by-step-by-step procedure for installing mod_mono, 
then configuring it for Apache.

I have some technical expertise.

Thanx in advance for any replies,

Slowly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I set up a mono web server on a Linux box, I follow this guide: [How to get ASP.NET MVC 2 working with Mono in 10 Steps](http://buddylindsey.com/how-to-get-asp-net-mvc-2-working-with-mono-in-10-steps/)

It looks like there are also ports available for xsp and mod_mono on MacPorts, but they're pretty outdated: [mono on MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=category&substr=mono)

The first link should get you on your way. You'll just have to iron out any differences in the compilation steps.